I need to add a modal on one classic ASP page, but inly if a cookie has not been set. i'd like to avoid javascript
I have a classic ASP page that needs a modal to pop up asking people to sign up to our mailing list. If they sign up, a cookie is set. This page checks for that cookie and doesn't harass the user if they've already signed up (a cookie is set).
I saw a similar routine using a lot of JavaScript, but I couldn't get it to work. (I'm very weak in JavaScript.)
So I tried the following using classic ASP and the bare minimum of Javascript, which doesn't display the modal at all.
Here's the basic code I'm working with.
<code>
<body>
<%
' Get the cookie
KeepInTouch = Request.Cookies("KeepInTouch")

if KeepInTouch <> "Y" then
%>
<script>
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
</script>
<div id="popup" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <!-- ... rest of popup ... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</code>

I can't get the modal to pop up, even without checking for the cookie.

Your script element is positioned before the popup div.  Put it after.

javascript is the correct way to do this
